# How to get a FILE* stream from a file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, file

We can get a file descriptor from a FILE* stream by using the `fileno()` function. Is there a function for getting a FILE* stream from the file descriptor without reopening the file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
   FILE *fdopen(int fd, const char *mode);
```

See `fdopen(3)`, but it should be on the same page as `fopen(3)`:

> The `fdopen()` function  associates  a  stream  with  the  existing 
>   file    descriptor,  *fd*.   The mode of the stream (one of the values
>   `"r"`, `"r+"`,    `"w"`, `"w+"`, `"a"`, `"a+"`) must be compatible
>   with  the  mode of the file descriptor.  The file position indicator
>   of the new stream is set to that belonging to *fd*, and the  error and
>   end-of-file  indicators  are cleared.   Modes  `"w"` or `"w+"` do not
>   cause truncation of the file.  The file descriptor is not `dup`’ed,
>   and will be closed when the stream  created  by  `fdopen()`  is 
>   closed.  The  result of applying `fdopen()` to a shared memory object
>   is undefined.